# Given markov chain $X \rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z$, $X^2 \rightarrow Y^2 \rightarrow Z^2$ is not a Markov chain

Tags: probability, functions, markov-chains, markov-process

Consider the  markov chain $X \rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z$.  $f(X) \rightarrow f(Y) \rightarrow f(Z)$ is not a Markov chain in general.

I want to find an example for this. I managed to figure out that if $f$ injective, then $f(X) \rightarrow f(Y) \rightarrow f(Z)$ is a markov chain.

I found $f(a) = a^2$, a non-injective function and this example:

$P(X = 1) = 1/4, P(X = -1) = 3/4$, the same for $Y$ and $Z$.

Then I managed to show that $X \rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z$ is a Markov chain because $P(X|Y) \cdot P(Z | Y) = P(X,Z | Y)$. Now I want to show that:
$P(f(X)|f(Y)) \cdot P(f(Z)|f(Y)) \neq P(f(X), f(Z) | f(Y))$ but I don't know how to go on. No matter what I try, equality holds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done even in the setting of deterministic dynamics. Consider the deterministic dynamics $-2 \to -1 \to 1 \to 2 \to -2$. Consider $f(x)=x^2$. Notice that

$$P(X_{n+1}^2=4 \mid X_n=-1)=0 \\
P(X_{n+1}^2=4 \mid X_n=1)=1.$$

Yet $X_n^2$ is the same in both cases. If we can separate these cases by conditioning on older values of $X_n^2$, then $X_n^2$ is not Markov. And indeed:

$$P(X_{n+1}^2=4 \mid X_n^2=1,X_{n-1}^2=4)=0 \\
P(X_{n+1}^2=4 \mid X_n^2=1,X_{n-1}^2=1)=1$$

so $X_n^2$ is not Markov.

Comment: Why do I have to consider $X_n = -1$ here? This can never happen because we apply the quadratic function to all $X$.

Comment: @今天春天 In my notation $X_n$ is the chain with the signs still included (on four states). The point is that the distribution of $X_{n+1}^2$ needs "more information" than $X_n^2$ to be specified, and so it will turn out to not be conditionally independent of the past (in particular, in this case, of $X_{n-1}^2$). Indeed $P(X_{n+1}^2=4 \mid X_n^2=1,X_{n-1}^2=4)$ and $P(X_{n+1}^2=4 \mid X_n^2=1,X_{n-1}^2=1)$ are not the same. Note that the former conditioning is just $X_n=-1$ while the latter conditioning is just $X_n=1$.

Comment: So if we assume $P(X_n) = -2 = P(X_n) = 2 = 1/8$ and $P(X_n = -1) = P(X_n = 1) = 3/8$ then $P(X_{n+1}^2 = 4 | X_n^2 = 1, X_{n-1}^2 = 4) = ((2/8)* (6/8) * (6/8)) / ((6/8) * (6/8))= 1/4$ but $P(X_{n+1}^2 = 4 | X_n^2 = 1, X_{n-1}^2 = 1) = ((2/8)* (6/8) * (2/8)) / ((6/8) * (2/8))= 1/4$, but this is the same?

Comment: @今天春天 Why are you making the distribution of $X_n$ random at all? Just notice that $X_2^2$ is dependent on $X_0^2$ even conditioned on $X_1^2$.

Comment: If we assume the distributions are equal?

Comment: I don't get why $X_2^2$ depends on $X_0^2$.

Comment: Take $X_0$ to be say uniformly distributed on $\{ -2,-1 \}$. Then the joint distribution of $(X_0,X_1,X_2)$ is uniformly distributed on $\{ (-2,-1,1),(-1,1,2) \}$. Take the square: $(X_0^2,X_1^2,X_2^2)$ is uniformly distributed on $\{ (4,1,1),(1,1,4) \}$. Note that both of these triples have the same value of $X_1^2$ but different values of $X_2^2$. (Please excuse my last comment, it was a bit misleading.)

Comment: $X_0$ should be uniformly distributed on ${-2, -1, 1, 2}$, shouldn't it?

Comment: I still can't see the problem.

Comment: @今天春天 No, I specifically decided to make it uniformly distributed on $\{ -2,-1 \}$. This gives the distributions for $(X_0,X_1,X_2)$ and $(X_0^2,X_1^2,X_2^2)$ that I wrote. Now note that the two values of $X_1^2$ are the same, so it is as if we already conditioned on $X_1^2=1$. Then $P(X_2^2=4) P(X_0^2=1)=1/4$ but $P(X_2^2=4 \text{ and } X_0^2=1)=1/2$, so the two are not independent. (By the way, the uniformity was not necessary: any distribution for $X_0$ assigning positive probability to $-2$ and to $-1$ and to nothing else would have done the job.)

Comment: How do you get the joint distributions from saying that $X_0$ is uniformly distributed?

Comment: @今天春天 Because I specified the dynamics too: they follow the deterministic dynamics $-2 \to -1 \to 1 \to 2 \to -2$.

Comment: Just an (off topic) side question: would it be possible to say $f(X_i)=X_i + X_{i-1}$ or is this function invalid?

Comment: @今天春天 No, that does not make sense (at least not in the sense meant in your question). You could argue that on the left "X_i" stands for $\{ X_i \}$, i.e. the whole sequence, but again that is not the meaning intended in your question.