# A function of a Markov chain is necessarily again a Markov chain?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process, information-theory

I was curious about the above questions. If the answer is not, is there a mathematical proof of that?

e.g. given a function $f:\mathcal X \rightarrow \mathcal Y$, with $\mathcal X$ a finite state space, **find** a Markov Chain $(X_n)_{n\ge 0}$ such that $(Y_n)_{n\ge 0}$ with $Y_n = f(X_n)$ is not a Markov Chain.

Comment: Related, recent:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2257532/given-markov-chain-x-rightarrow-y-rightarrow-z-x2-rightarrow-y2-righta

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This depends on $f$. In fact, $Y_n=f(X_n)$ is a Markov chain in $\mathcal Y$ for every Markov chain $(X_n)$ in $\mathcal X$ if and only if $f$ is either injective or constant. If $f$ is constant then $(Y_n)$ is trivially a Markov chain. If $f$ is injective, then
$$P(Y_{n+1}=y_{n+1}|Y_k=y_k\text{ for }k\le n)=P(X_{n+1}=f^{-1}(y_{n+1})|X_k=f^{-1}(y_k)\text{ for }k\le n)\\
=P(X_{n+1}=f^{-1}(y_{n+1})|X_n=f^{-1}(y_n))=P(Y_{n+1}=y_{n+1}|Y_n=y_n).$$
However, if $f$ is neither injective nor constant, there exists $y,z\in\mathcal Y$ and $x_1,x_2,x_3\in\mathcal X$ (with $x_1\neq x_2$) such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=y\neq z=f(x_3)$. Define a transition kernel on $\mathcal X$ by $p(x_1,x_3)=p(x_3=x_1)=1$, $p(x,x)=1$ otherwise. In other words the chain stays where it is with probability one unless it is at $x_1$ or $x_3$, in which case it switches.

Assuming $X_0$ is uniformly distributed on $\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$, we have
$$P(Y_2=z|Y_1=y)=\frac{P(Y_2=z,Y_1=y)}{P(Y_1=y)}=\frac{P(X_0=x_3)}{P(X_0\in\{x_1,x_3\})}=\frac12.$$
Let's break down the steps. The first step is just definition of conditional probability. The second comes from noting that $Y_1=y,Y_2=z$ if and only if $X_1=x_1,X_2=x_3$ (otherwise the chain cannot move) which happens if and only if $X_0=x_3$, and similarly $Y_1=y$ if and only if either $X_0=x_1$ or $X_0=x_3$. The third step comes from the fact that $X_0$ is uniform over $\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$.

On the other hand, we have
$$P(Y_2=z|Y_0=z,Y_1=y)=\frac{P(Y_0=z,Y_1=y,Y_2=z)}{P(Y_0=z,Y_1=y)}=\frac{P(X_0=x_3)}{P(X_0=x_3)}=1$$
using similar steps. These are not equal, so $(Y_n)$ is not a Markov chain.

Comment: How do you know that $f^{-1}(y_n$ exists? Or isn't it a problem?

Comment: If $f$ is not injective, $$P(f(X)=k)=P(X\in f^{-1}(k)).$$ So at the end, you can consider these equality as inclusion (I think) @MarineGalantin

Comment: Is not? What do you mean?

Comment: What "is not" ? $\mathbb P(f(X)=k)=\mathbb P(X\in f^{-1}(k))$ ? Of course it is ! Simply because $$f(X)=k\iff X\in f^{-1}(k).$$ @MarineGalantin

Comment: But at the end, in this answer, the OP precise that $f$ is injective so it's really an equality : "If  is injective, then...". Maybe in the futur you should read more carefully answers before asking question ;) @MarineGalantin

Comment: I am reading the whole answer, but I don't get how $$ P(Y_n = y_n) = P(X_n = f^{-1} (y_n ) ) $$ first because for me $ f^{-1} (y_n ) $ is a set. BTW, I don't see where somewhere else injectivity could have been used so I assume that you write $=$ between a set and a random variable using injectivity of $f$, i.e. $f^{-1} (y_n )$ is a set of maximum $1$ element. But still, the set could be empty, and I don't understand why this isn't a problem (cf. first comment). What do you think?

Comment: Indeed $x=\{2\}$ has a priori no sense strictly talking. But math use some "slang", and you should be aware that $x=\{2\}$ is an obvious notation for $x=2$.

Comment: @user657324 So is it where the injectivity of the function is used? And I imagine that if the set is empty, by definition the probability will be equal to zero.

Comment: @user657324 after thinking deeply about it, I have that one question : what would happen if $$f^{-1} ( y_n ) = \emptyset $$ what does it mean to write :

$$P(Y_{n+1}=y_{n+1}|Y_k=y_k\text{ for }k\le n)=P(X_{n+1}= \emptyset |X_k= \emptyset \text{ for }k\le n)\\ $$

Comment: To be clear, in this context $f^{-1}$ refers to the inverse, not the pre-image. If $f$ is injective, its inverse $f^{-1}:\mathcal Z \to \mathcal X$ is well-defined, where $\mathcal Z$ is the image of $f$. It is obvious that the $Y_n=f(X_n)\in\mathcal Z$, so there is no need to consider $Y_n=y_n$ for $y_n\notin\mathcal Z$.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily, for a general criteria see
["Markov property for a function of a Markov chain: A linear algebra approach"](http://ledoux.perso.math.cnrs.fr/JL-LG-LAA05.pdf)