Is it possible to reduce a Markov chain?
"Reduce" is probably not the right words, although I'm not sure what the accepted name for this operation is, or whether it is well defined at all.
Say you have a Markov system with states $s_1,s_2,\dots$, and I want to regard some states as equivalent, namely I want to describe a new system where the new states are collections of some of the old states, e.g. $s'_1=\{s_1,s_4\}$, $s'_2=\{s_7,s_8,s_{11}\}$, etc. Does this define a new Markov chain? And if so, how is the new transition matrix obtained from the old one?
For example one could consider a random walk on a 2d lattice, so we have probabilities $P((i,j)\to(i',j'))$. But perhaps, for whatever reason, I do not care about the vertical position of the particle, only the horizontal one, so instead of labelling states by $(i,j)$ I want to label them by $i$ only, so $s'_i=\{s_{i,j}\}_{j=1,2,\dots}$. What is $P(i\to i')$ as a function of $P((i,j)\to(i',j'))$?

"Lumped Markov chains" are not necessarily Markov chains. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2262424/a-function-of-a-markov-chain-is-necessarily-again-a-markov-chain
